# PartialEq on Array

Tags: arrays, rust, deriving

Question about rust arrays (the constant size ones, [T, ..Size]). I am trying to make the following work:

```
#[deriving(PartialEq)]
struct Test {
  dats : [f32, ..16]
}
```

I know I could not use deriving and simply write my own PartialEq, but that is rather obnoxious... The error message that is given is also cryptic to me (see bellow). Is there a proper rustic way to do this?

```
rustc ar.rs 
ar.rs:4:3: 4:20 error: mismatched types: expected `&&[f32]` but found `&[f32, .. 16]` (expected &-ptr but found vector)
ar.rs:4   dat : [f32, ..16]
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of #[deriving]
ar.rs:2:1: 3:7 note: expansion site
ar.rs:4:3: 4:20 error: mismatched types: expected `&&[f32]` but found `&[f32, .. 16]` (expected &-ptr but found vector)
ar.rs:4   dat : [f32, ..16]
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of #[deriving]
ar.rs:2:1: 3:7 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to 2 previous error
```

I am on the rust nightly build from today.

Thanks!

Comment: It's currently not possible to parameterize `Size`, so the compiler cannot derive any traits. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug: [#7622](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/7622) "Fixed-length arrays implement no traits". As A.B. said, there is no way to parameterise the length of a fixed-length array, so the only way to implement traits is to actually write them out:

```
impl PartialEq for [f32, .. 0] { ... }

impl PartialEq for [f32, .. 1] { ... }

impl PartialEq for [f32, .. 2] { ... }

impl PartialEq for [f32, .. 3] { ... }

// ...
```

(Of course this *could* be done with a macro: but it still isn't feasible to do all possible lengths for all possible traits.)

You'll need to implement the traits yourself without `deriving`, e.g.

```
struct Test { dats: [f32, .. 16] }

impl PartialEq for Test {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Test) -> bool {
        self.dats == other.dats
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Test { dats: [0.0, .. 16 ]};
    let b = Test { dats: [100.0, .. 16 ]};

    println!("{}", a == b);
}
```

You might think it strange that you can use `==` with `[f32, .. 16]` without it implementing `PartialEq` (which is how one overloads `==` for most types, like `Test` above): it works because the compiler has a built-in understanding of how `==` works with fixed length vectors and so uses that directly without touch the trait.

Comment: Great! I would have never have guessed == would work. I was going to do a nasty for loop :(.

Comment: What to do if array is longer than 30 (like, 64)
`an implementation of 'std::cmp::PartialEq' might be missing for '[u32; 64]'`

Comment: @kirhgoff the arrays can be coerced to slices `&self.dats[..] == &other.dats[..]`, e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c91c2caba521931e954e8f6128dce13e